# Can I use Hive on Azure Databricks without Hadoop/HDInsight?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-hdinsight, databricks, azure-blob-storage

[The Docs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/advanced/external-hive-metastore.html) says "Every Databricks deployment has a central Hive metastore..." besides an external metastore for existing Hive installations.

I have an Azure Databricks workspace with an underlying spark cluster, and a datafiles stored on DBFS and Blob Storage. Do I need HDInsight cluster with external metastore to be able to create and use Hive tables? Or can I use the above mentioned central metastore to create Hive tables on data stored on DBFS or Blob storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gadam nope you do not. Azure Databricks provisions its own Hive Metastore, but if you are already using one with HDInsight, Databricks can be configured to also use it (an external metastore).

Comment: Thanks @c.-fish. I went through the [spark-sql programming guide][1] and it says Persistent tables are one way of using Hive, and Spark creates a metastore in the current directory when external metastore is not specified. Are these viable for production environments? Is there any blog/resource that can expand on your answer? Thanks! 1. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#overview

Comment: @Gadam yeah these are certainly viable for prod, Spark creates it's own Hive Metastore if you don't give it an external one to work with. Typically the main reason to use an external metastore is if you are also using Hive/Hadoop elsewhere and want to store your external tables in a single location. If you don't already have a use for an external HMS, I would recommend just letting Databricks use the internal one.